# making use of otherwise wasted padding space

Tags: c++, optimization, memory, padding, nested

The following struct `X` has 3 bytes of payload and 1 byte of padding:

```
struct X
{
    short a;
    char b;
};

memory layout: aab.
```

The following struct `Y` has 4 bytes of payload and 2 byte of padding:

```
struct Y
{
    X x;
    char c;
};

memory layout: aab.c.
```

Is there any way to keep `X` nested inside of `Y` and have `sizeof(X) == 4 && sizeof(Y) == 4`?

```
memory layout: aabc
```

Ideally, I would want this kind of space optimization for all types `X` (think `X` as a template parameter).

Comment: Why do you want to disable padding?  If you intend on using this for serialization, I don't recommend this approach.

Comment: I don't want to disable padding. I want `X` to be padded and Y to use the padding space of `X` for the additional char.

Comment: So you're trying to "inline" `X` into `Y` conceptually?

Comment: Answering in a comment because this would be serious downvote-bait, but if you're not proud (like me), you could just say `#define X short a; char b`. If you really need that member `x` in there, you could probably manage it somehow, like by token-pasting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For hopefully obvious reasons the size of both `X` and `Y` can't be four (if it were possible, `X` would have multiple definitions, the normal padded one and one where the padding is used by the `char` of `Y`). So the only way `Y` could be 4 is if `X` were changed to eliminate its padding. This can be done by compiler specific pragmas or directives. However, since that could result in `X` being accessed unaligned it would effectively restrict possible portability of your program (some architectures will even crash if misaligned accesses are made).

Instead, can you explain more clearly the end result you're hoping to achieve here?

Comment: If you were to use a compiler-specific pragma or directive to disable padding for `X`, wouldn't the complier do the proper un-packing when accessing a member of `X`? ... That is typically why there is a performance hit for packed structures, right?

Comment: @Jason Hopefully your compiler would understand that the target system can't do the mis-aligned accesses on its own and generate the code. There's nothing in the standard that talks about directives like `pack` so you really can't make any guarantees for a particular compiler.

Answer (score 1):

This is a compiler setting. Padding is necessary for the memory access to work correctly in some cases. In some architectures it's a matter of efficiency, in others the program will crash if not properly aligned. In this case you have 16 bits alignment, and accessing `c` directly on an odd address may cause troubles.

However, you can force the alignment to be turned off by using [`pack` pragma](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa273913%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) (or whatever else option your compiler has for it).

The question is why. If you rely on that - you make your program potentially not portable and unpredictable on various architectures.

Answer (score 1):

If you are lucky and, unlike in your example, X is not POD, then derivation can help

```
struct X
{
  X(){} // not POD
  short a;
  char b;
};
struct Y : X
{
  char c;
};
```

Y has size 4 with the itanium ABI on x86_64.

Comment: Do you know the rationale for the constraint of X not being a POD?

Comment: [The Itanium ABI](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#pod) says "We ignore tail padding for PODs because an early version of the standard did not allow us to use it for anything else and because it sometimes permits faster copying of the type."

Comment: Ok, thus it isn't a standard requirement,  just an implementation choice of the Itanium ABI.

Answer (score 0):

You can force alignment with a pragma:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct X
{
    short a;
    char b;
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

This is supported by Microsoft's C++ compiler.  I don't know if this is a portable way of performing this.

Comment: That only works if I have control over the definition of X, right?

Comment: Since #pragma is a pre-processor command, it will be set for the duration, meaning if X is in a header file you don't control you can apply this prior to including it and ALL items in that header file will be packed to a 1-byte boundary.  However, if you don't own X, it raises even more questions about whether or not you really should be doing this.

Comment: @Chad: using `#pragma pack` around a header is very risky (existing compiled code might not like this at all, you'll need to recompile on the other side anyways.

Comment: I believe g++ has an extension which supports it as well.

Comment: @André Caron - I make no claim that it is safe, just noting that it is possible.

Comment: `#pragma` is **not** a pre-processor directive. Just because it starts with `#` doesn't make it so. C99 even introduced the `_Pragma()` form so that pragmas could be generated by the preprocessor.

Comment: To clarify, `#pragma` is a directive, and C99 introduced the `_Pragma()` operator.  Reference:  http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Pragmas.html and http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/

Answer (score 0):

In `gcc` you can declare your structure using the `__attribute__((packed))` keyword in order to maintain a certain byte-alignment or padding.

So for instance, you could do something like

```
typedef struct X
{
    short a;
    char b;
} __attribute__((packed)) X;

typedef struct Y
{
    X x;
    char c;
} __attribute__((packed)) Y;
```

Now `sizeof(Y)` will be 4 bytes ... the only issue is that you will pay a performance penalty for any unpacking that needs to be done in order to meet the byte-alignment requirements of your hardware platform.

Comment: That only works if I have control over the definition of X, right?

Comment: Yes, it does seem that way ... once you have declared X, you can't re-define its alignment to something shorter using another `typedef`.

Comment: Actually, declaring the first member of `Y` as `X x __attribute__((packed));` without touching the original definition of `X` gets the size down to 5, although it cannot go all the way to 4.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it's not standard C/C++ and requires compiler-specific extensions.  For MSVC, use the [`pack` pragma](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct X 
{
    ...
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

For GCC, use the [`packed` type attribute](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Type-Attributes.html):

```
struct __atribute__((packed)) X
{
    ...
};
```

With some preprocessor macros and the [`__pragma` token](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9x1s805%28v=VS.80%29.aspx), you can make a definition work in both compilers without requiring a bunch of `#if` conditionals.

Comment: That only works if I have control over the definition of X, right?

Answer (score 0):

the question boils down to this: how can i have the inner struct's *sizeof* be *packed* when nesting it, and *padded* for proper alignment when allocating it? answer: i can't, because the language provides no way to declare that, and all the __attribute__s and #pragmas don't help.

the most obvious workaround is aliasing the whole structure:

```
struct X
{
    short a;
    char b;
};

struct Y
{
    short a;
    char b;
    char c;
};
```

however, this has the downside that you need to make an explicit cast whenever you want to slice the structure:

```
X_taking_fct(*(struct X *)&Y_var);
```

on the upside, accessing the outer structure's members is natural:

```
char_taking_fct(Y_var.c);
```

this situation can be inverted:

```
struct X
{
    short a;
    char b;
};

union Y
{
    struct X x;
    struct {
        short a;
        char b;
        char c;
    } extra;
};
```

now you can do this:

```
X_taking_fct(Y_var.x);
```

at the cost of needing this:

```
char_taking_fct(Y_var.extra.c);
```

enter C11 anonymous structures (gcc supported this for much longer):

```
struct X
{
    short a;
    char b;
};

union Y
{
    struct X x;
    struct {
        // the dummy_ prefix is not strictly necessary, but avoids confusion
        short dummy_a;
        char dummy_b;
        char c;
    };
};
```

now accessing both inner and outer members is natural:

```
X_taking_fct(Y_var.x);
char_taking_fct(Y_var.c);
```

however, there is no way to avoid the redundant declaration of the members. this is obviously ugly and introduces a risk of running out of sync. by putting the inner struct's body inside a macro, at least the risk can be avoided:

```
#define X_body(pfx) \
    short pfx##a; \
    char pfx##b

struct X
{
    X_body();
};

union Y
{
    struct X x;
    struct {
        X_body(dummy_);
        char c;
    };
};
```